# How can I sort my "contacted" column in my table which is connected to a live mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, backend

Front end code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Stats.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";



function Stats() {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []); 

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5 //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited+customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key ) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })
    //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
    //page change
    const changePage = ({selected}) => {
      setPageNumber(selected);
    }

   
  

  {/*}
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCurrentTime(data.time);
        });
    }, []);
  */}
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
      <table className="customertable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Counts of Visit</th>
          <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
          <th>Contacted?</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {displayCustomers} 
        </tbody>
        
      </table>
      <ReactPaginate 
          previousLabel={"Previous"}
          nextLabel={"Next"}
          pageCount={pageCount}
          onPageChange={changePage}
          containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
          pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
          previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
          nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
          disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
          activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

Backend code

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      {/*}
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocalDateString('en-CA');
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocalTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
    */}
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

So I have my front end as well as back end code shown above in react. As you can see I am making SQL statements to pull data from mySQL.

How do I sort the frontend table on the contacted column? So for example I have a few rows and contacted column shows Yes or No, but I want to be able to click on Contacted then sort the column, so all the "No" will be shown than "Yes"

Answer (score 1):

Create a columnClickHandler function. inside that function sort the customerList following way, then update the customerList.it will sort the customerList based on contacted column in ascending order. means all "no"s will come first since lexically "n" is lower than "y" .

```
customerList.sort((a,b)=>{

    if(a.contacted<b.contacted){
        return -1
    }
    else{
        return 1
    }
    })
```

now here comes the question what if you need to sort the list in descending order upon user's second click on column and finally get back to the genuine order it received from database in the final click . if you want to continue this cycle , you might have to track users click with a state. then upon current's state of the click, you have to update the list in expected order. to preserve the genuine order it received from the database,you can add a separate state.

Comment: please elaborate!